# Proof of if $U,W$ are finite subspaces of $V$, then $dim(U \oplus W)\leq dim(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, alternative-proof

What I did:

- Using the theorem of sum of subspaces I have $dim(U \oplus W) = dim(U) + dim(W)$
- It's not hard to verify that $U \cap W = \{ 0 \} \Rightarrow \{u_{1},...,u_{n},w_{1},...,w_{m}\}$ is l.i. ($n=dim(U),\ m=dim(W)$)
- Assume $dim(V) < dim(U)+dim(W)$
- As 2 l.i. subspaces have together greater dimension than the $V$ space itself, there exists a vector of $[u_{1},...,u_{n},w_{1},...,w_{m}]$ that can't be written as a linear combination of $V$ basis vectors (verifiable). Which leads to a contradiction.

I think maybe there's a more simple solution, if anyone knows post it here please.

Comment: $U \oplus W$ is $U \times W$ or $U+W$?

Comment: Can you show that any subspace has dimension smaller or equal than the space itself?

Comment: @Johnny Lemmon Do you see a problem ?

Comment: @azif00 it is defined as the direct sum, where $U \cap W = \{0\}$

Comment: @PieroA.L.Ribeiro no, I was trying to suggest an easier way to prove the claim

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon sorry, I could see now. Indeed, if you use a known proven fact like: in any space of $n$ dimension, any $m>n$ sequence of vectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: Note $U+V$ is subspace of $V$, so $\dim (U+V)\leq \dim (V)$. You don’t need independent property on $U,V$.

Comment: @user264745 For me this relation of subspace and dimension is not as direct as you pointed out.